# “Failed to install SGD client” when accessing the secure global desktop from OS X

Tags: macos, java, oracle

I am having an issue since I have upgraded to OS X Yosemite.

I used to previously remotely access my work's Windows system from my Mac (OS X Mavericks). I had installed XQuartz and Java and was using Firefox as my browser.

Since I upgraded to OS X Yosemite with both Java and XQuartz installed I can access the secure global desktop site and can also enter my log in details.

The screen then moves to "loading" and then freezes with a final message that states "Failed to install SGD client".

Any ideas as to what I am doing wrong? Never got that message with OS X Mavericks.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue with "Failed to istall SGD client" and found the following reference to XQuartz issues - it seems to fix this issue as well.

https://discussions.apple.com/thread/6616720

Comment: The linked page essentially says to re-install XQuartz, which will create or re-create some required links.